# How to set cell padding in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Does anyone know how it's possible to set cell padding in PHPExcel ?
Searched for 30mins and still can't find a proper solution.
There is no useful documentation on this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Maybe

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setIndent(1);
```

Comment: Excellent, man! For everybody with the same problem: In PHPExcel, they call it `indentation`, not padding or margin.

Comment: How to do this in LaravelExcel?

Comment: as of the time of writing this comment, still works in PHPSpreadsheet.

Comment: Could not find this under PHPSpreadsheet Docs so thank you for posting this code. Confirmed working under PHP version 7.3.28 as of this date.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add, please note that this will only work if the horizontal alignment is set to left or right.

Should precede with this (if it has not already been done)

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to expand a column. I have found a solution. You can set column dimension to auto size. Here is an example

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
```

I have used this approach in my laravle 9 project.

Edit: Found a way to do it dynamically

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$columnIndex = 'A';

foreach ($sheet->getColumnIterator($columnIndex) as $column) {
    $columnIndex = $column->getColumnIndex();
    $maxWidth = 0;
        foreach ($column->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
            $text = $cell->getValue();
            $width = mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8');
            $maxWidth = max($maxWidth, $width);
        }
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnIndex)->setWidth($maxWidth+1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cell Padding is an HTML concept, and there is nothing like it in Excel. How would you set cell padding in MS Excel itself?

Probably the best you can manage is setting the cell height and width.

**EDIT**

I've been googling this, and even [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/excel-2007-is-there-a-way-to-create-cell-margins/716e6b06-fe98-404b-91dd-095ea544b4d3?msgId=075deee5-f2d8-4f78-b161-ffcfa666fee0) say that there is no equivalent of cell padding in Excel. The best option seems to be using cell alignment indents (combined with column width) for horizontal padding; and row height and vertical alignment for vertical padding. These can be set in PHPExcel.

Comment: Nope, cell padding (or "inner margin" or "content margin" etc.) is a general concept in layouts, software and documents. MS Excel, OpenOffice and LibreOffice can do this. I'm talking about the popular PHP library ["PHPExcel"](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) here, so this has nothing to do with HTML

Comment: I'm trying to identify how to set an inner or content margin in MS Excel without success, nor can I find either of those terms related to spreadsheet cells (rather than page print layout, or embedded tables) in the ECMA or BIFF documentation for xlsx or xls files. I'm somewhat familiar with PHPExcel: if I'm not familiar with elements like cellpadding, then it's unlikely to be in PHPExcel... but if you can point me to the relevant parts of the documentation, I can look at implementing it.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look on how this is called, but IT'S THERE, i've been working with Excel for nearly 10years and done this several times. To make clear what i mean: the amount of pixels/pt from the content to the border of the cell.

Comment: Lovely, downvoted for being honest. My apologies to Panique for not being as familiar with PHPExcel as he'd like me to be.... especially as he never did get back with what cell padding actually meant to him. I'm going to stop trying to answer his questions, because he seems to downvote on principle, because I can't relate his terminology to that used by Microsoft.

Comment: Hey, just to clarify: downvoting is useful to different useful answers from wrong ones, this is nothing personal. In this case, the answer was simply wrong (beacuse you were talking about Excel, we were talking about PHPExcel, which are totally different things). And SO does not allow to correct a downvote "unless the anwser is edited". Sorry!

Comment: Gee, I really do love being downvoted, when my edit of Sep 20 '12 at 18:16 predates the accepted and upvoted answer that says exactly the same thing by 10 months.... I'm beginning to get the feeling that people hate honesty here

Comment: Can you edit your answer, then I can remove the downvote (SO doesn't allow to take back a downvote for weird reasons btw). Or delete the answer (that's wrong) to get back the point :)

Comment: Well the edit that I'd originally posted on 20-Sep-2012 did say to use indents, which wasn't wrong..... and which is exactly what the upvoted and accepted answer says to do..... so I rather object to being told I'm wrong, especially when I've cited Microsofts own documentation on the subject as well